# FlashDevelop / Haxe - build halted with errors (haxelib.exe)

Tags: android, flashdevelop, haxe, nme, openfl

I'm trying to get started with Haxe but I can't even get past the easiest step, compiling the "new project" template. I'm using FlashDevelop 4, installed Haxe and used the the command `haxelib install openfl` to install openfl (did the same for NME) though I still get the most basic compiler error:

```
haxelib run openfl build C:\dev\haxeBox\openFlTest\application.xml android -debug 
[file_contents,C:\Program Files(x86)\Haxe\haxe\lib\openfl//.current]
Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe).
```

I've googled a couple of hours but I couldn't find anything that would remotely point me into the right direction, therefore I hope anybody has solved this issue before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had OpenFL downloaded but not successfully installed.
I did install haxe to `\Program Files(x86)\Haxe` but didn't execute the setup commands with admin rights. If you run into that issue make sure either you got the nessecarry rights when executing:

```
haxelib install lime
haxelib run lime setup
lime install openfl
```

Otherwise `haxelib run lime setup` won't do anything.

If you get stuck at another point, try the [official setup guide](https://www.openfl.org/download/).