# Flashdevelop / HaxePunk: Build halted with errors

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop, haxepunk

I've been trying to follow [this](http://haxecoder.com/post.php?id=31) tutorial to get started with HaxePunk. I am using FlashDevelop and have got to trying to run the program after adding the logo.png. However, when I run the program I get the following output:

```
Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "D:\Haxe Projects\Prj_Starting\Prj_Starting.hxproj" -ipc f201d2c5-2ffe-46d4-bb54-c67a3e34ab4a -version "3.2.1" -compiler "C:\Program Files\HaxeToolkit\haxe" -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library" -target "neko" 
Building Prj_Starting
Running Pre-Build Command Line...
cmd: "C:\Program Files\HaxeToolkit\haxe/haxelib" run lime build "project.xml" neko -debug -Dfdb
[file_contents,C:\Program Files\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\lime//.current]
Build halted with errors.
Done(1)
```

No error specific error is given so I am unsure what is wrong. I have followed the tutorial exactly and these are my classes:

Main.hx

```
import com.haxepunk.Engine;
import com.haxepunk.HXP;

class Main extends Engine
{

    override public function init()
    {
#if debug
        HXP.console.enable();
#end
        HXP.scene = new MainScene();
    }

    public static function main() { new Main(); }

}
```

MainScene.hx

```
import com.haxepunk.Scene;

class MainScene extends Scene
{
    public override function begin()
    {
        add(new Logo());
    }
}
```

Logo.hx

```
package src;
import com.haxepunk.Entity;
import com.haxepunk.graphics.Image;
import com.haxepunk.utils.Input;
import com.haxepunk.utils.Key;

/**
 * Logo entity.
 * @author Abigail Smith
 */
 class Logo extends Entity
{

    private var speed:Int;

    public function new() 
    {
        super(270, 190);
        speed = 5;
        graphic = new Image("graphics/logo.png");
    }

    public override function update():Void {
        if (Input.check(Key.RIGHT)) {
            moveBy(speed, 0);
        }
        if (Input.check(Key.LEFT)) {
            moveBy(-speed, 0);
        }
        if (Input.check(Key.DOWN)) {
            moveBy(0, speed);
        }
        if (Input.check(Key.UP)) {
            moveBy(0, -speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this solving this error would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: This [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22596766/2631715) seems similar. Does that answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem with one of the library you need that called "lime".

```
[file_contents,C:\Program Files\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\lime//.current]
```

1. Open **cmd** and type **haxelib list**
2. Check if you can see **lime** library there
3. If it's there then run **haxelib update lime** else you need to install it by running **haxelib install lime**

Hope this solves your problem!